# how to write only a portion of text file from an array

Tags: python, numpy, python-re

I am new to python and I want to write a 2darray in an existing text file I wanna write each row of my array in a particular column in my text file Columns are separated by -1 or 155 and then the next row will be written. I have tried np.savetxt() but it has totally changed the content of my file and removed my previous data which were fixed and should not be changed.
here is the content of my text file and where I want to replace data and my 2darray.

my 2darray with 155 rows 60

```
columns = [[ -80.  -80. -120. ... -240. -150. -200.]
 [ -81.  -81. -120. ... -240. -150. -200.]
 [ -82.  -82. -120. ... -240. -150. -200.]
 ...
 [-232. -232. -120. ... -240. -150. -200.]
 [-233. -233. -120. ... -240. -150. -200.]
 [-234. -234. -120. ... -240. -150. -200.]]
```

and the content of my text file I just want to change negative values

```
#GMSCOMMENT dff624bf-1700-4ec3-9c06-dafb4343152f POINT 9 599749.0 3736069.0
#GMSCOMMENT dff624bf-1700-4ec3-9c06-dafb4343152f POINT 8 597884.0 3732438.0
#GMSCOMMENT dff624bf-1700-4ec3-9c06-dafb4343152f POINT 7 595341.0 3728359.0
#GMSCOMMENT dff624bf-1700-4ec3-9c06-dafb4343152f POINT 6 596740.0 3727891.0
#GMSCOMMENT dff624bf-1700-4ec3-9c06-dafb4343152f POINT 5 597183.0 3727111.0
#GMSCOMMENT dff624bf-1700-4ec3-9c06-dafb4343152f POINT 4 597409.0 3728109.0
#GMSCOMMENT dff624bf-1700-4ec3-9c06-dafb4343152f POINT 3 595162.0 3729256.0
#GMSCOMMENT dff624bf-1700-4ec3-9c06-dafb4343152f POINT 2 599108.0 3733118.0
#GMSCOMMENT dff624bf-1700-4ec3-9c06-dafb4343152f POINT 1 598147.0 3731832.0
155 740 AUX IFACE AUX QFACT AUX CELLGRP
       155         0         0
1 21 22 -18.0 0 1.0 1
1 7 14 -1520.129032 0 1.0 2
1 16 20 -929.0322581 0 1.0 3
1 16 16 -14.51612903 0 1.0 4
1 15 18 -18.58064516 0 1.0 5
1 16 18 -13.93548387 0 1.0 6
1 17 20 -557.4193548 0 1.0 7
1 17 19 -2.55483871 0 1.0 8
1 20 17 -138.6 0 1.0 9
1 18 14 -49.35483871 0 1.0 10
```

Comment: I dont understand the question.  alsom do you have code or what you have tried so far ?

Comment: if you want to write in existing file then you have to use `append mode` - ie. `"a"` in command `fh = open(filename, "a")` `fh.write(...)`. And if you want to replace between other lines then you have to read all to memory, replace it in memory, and write back all data (without `append mode`).

Comment: if you want to write rows as columns then first convert rows to columns in your array. File can't write column after colum but only row after row.

Comment: @furas 
exactly, I want to replace the content of my array row by row between other lines. Unfortunatly, I didn't get what exactly do you mean by reading the content to memory

Comment: I mean read full file to Python and keep in some variable (and variable means some place in memory RAM). You may keep as single string and use string's function to change it. OR keep as list of rows and it can be simpler to insert new rows between other rows.